# When release NSXMLParser?

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I am using NSXMLParser like this :

```
- (BOOL)parseXMLData:(NSData *)inData
{
 provisioningParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: inData]; // defined if .h

 [provisioningParser setDelegate:self];
 [provisioningParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
 [provisioningParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
 [provisioningParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
```

return [provisioningParser parse];
}

My question is when should I release NSXMLParser?
I believe it is automatically released when parsing is finished; is this true?
If yes, instruments indicate there is a leak.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you alloc'd it, you'll need to release it.  Just release it after calling parse:

```
BOOL rval = [provisioningParser parse];
[provisioningParser release];
return rval;
```

Also, from the looks of your code, it looks like you might be saving this in a member variable.  Is there a reason for doing that? If not, make it a local variable.  If so, you'll probably want to release it in the dealloc() method of your class instead of after calling parse().

Comment: Something strange happens.
My app crash when I release parser after parse call.
Is it possible that the parser is released on parserDidEndDocument delegate function ?

Here the backtrace :
in objc_msgSend ()
in NSPopAutoreleasePool ()
in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
in SendEvent ()
in PurpleEventTimerCallBack ()
in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
in GSEventRunModal ()
in GSEventRun ()
in -[UIApplication _run] ()
in UIApplicationMain ()

Answer (score 1):

The correct thing to do is to release it within the `dealloc` method since it's an instance variable. But your code is wrong for that scenario. Imagine calling `parseXMLData:` twice in a row. provisioningParser will be overwritten the second time, making it impossible to release it within your `dealloc`.

If you want it to be local, declare it local, and end the method with

```
return [[provisioningParser autorelease] parse];
```

You could allocate it with NXSMLParser 'parserWithData:' and not have to do any of this (still should move it local to the method though).